# How to compare values in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to compare the current version with available versions of a program. I want all the available versions greater than the current version. I don't know how I make this comparison:

Sample of `groovy.txt`:

```
11.6
```

Sampple of `groovy1.txt`:

```
9.6.3 9.6.6 9.6.8 9.6.9 9.6.11 9.6.12 9.6.16 10.14 10.14 10.16 11.4 11.6 11.7 11.8 11.9 11.11 12.4 12.6
```

When I do this, I am getting below error because of cast conversion in `av.findAll { it > cv }`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: It's important to provide a sample of the contents of the `groovy.txt` and `groovy1.txt` files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs because tokenize returns a list of strings which cannot be compared to a string. It happens at this line:

```
av.findAll { it > cv }
```

For `cv` use:

```
def cv = output.tokenize().collect { it.tokenize('.').collect { it as int } }.first()
```

For `av`:

```
def av = output2.tokenize().collect { it.tokenize('.').collect { it as  int } }
```

I turned version numbers like `9.6.11` in arrays like `[9, 6, 11]` to compare until find out if the number is greater.

Then write the code to compare the versions:

```
av.findAll { 
    def isVersionGreater
    it.indexed().any { i, v ->
        if (cv[i] == v) return false
        isVersionGreater = v > (cv[i] ?: 0)
        return true
    }
    return isVersionGreater
}.collect { it.join('.') }
```

AFAIK, unfortunately, Groovy doesn't have a Python equivalent of `[9, 6, 11] < [11, 1]` to compare versions.

Comment: I have another requirement. Currently ```isVersionGreater``` displays all the value greater than the current version value. But I want to display only the value which is greater than the decimal number but lesser than the whole number. Eg: 11.6 is current version and I the available version list is [11.8,11.11,12.3], here I want to display only [11.8,11.11] but not the 12, because its greater than the current value.

Comment: Just use `.remove { it[0] < cv[0] }` after `.findAll`.

Comment: Also, it's always better to write a new question...

Comment: Sorry will keep it next time for sure. But now, I am getting ```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Exception evaluating property 'findAll' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: findAll for class: java.lang.Integer``` this error.

Comment: changed the code like this ```av.findAll.remove { it[0] < cv[0] } { ```

Comment: When I say after findAll is after the closure (after the curly braces (`{`)). Before calling `.collect`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234783/discussion-between-alfred-hitchkock-and-maicon-mauricio).

Comment: is this something ```return isVersionGreater
}.remove { it[0] < cv[0] }.collect { it.join('.') }``` that you mentioned